# Is it possible to upgrade log4j to 2.17+ when using Solr 4.6

Tags: java, spring, solr, log4j, solrj

We have this really old solr version using in production, recently we found a vulnerability in log4j 1.12.x so thats why we need to upgrade either the solr or log4j version. My questions is can we upgrade the log4j version from the solr 4.6.0 version? Currently solr 4.6 uses log4j 1.12 and in our app.

I tried upgrading the solr but this will takes a lot of time because our application code is really old

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Most well-behaved applications (i.e. those that do not try to configure Log4j themselves) can use the `log4j-1.2-api` bridge (cf. [migration guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html)). You just need to try using it with Solr 4.6.

Comment: BTW: the CVEs published against Log4j 1.x are only the tip of all known vulnerabilities for Solr 4.6: cf. [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-core/4.6.0)